# Problems compiling with Quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly

Welcome to another of my questions about compiling! :P

So, after days of stress trying to compile my app, first manually, after porting the project to Quickly, I decided to create the project from scratch using this time Quickly. Now I've finished the app, it works great using `quickly run` and I haven't added *any* new file, just removed, replaced or modified. But it can't be compiled using `quickly package --verbose --extras`... why, if there doesn't seems to be errors related with my project?

The fail happens because `python-mkdebian` doesn't haves enough parameters to work.

The terminal output (in Spanish):

```
running install_egg_info
Writing /tmp/tmpsT6Pms/virtuam-0.1.egg-info
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  help/C/figures/icon.png
  help/C/index.page
  help/C/preferences.page
  help/C/topic1.page
  virtuam.desktop.in
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/python-mkdebian", line 368, in <module>
    egg = get_egg_info()
  File "/usr/bin/python-mkdebian", line 35, in get_egg_info
    k, v = l.strip().split(': ', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
Ha ocurrido un error al crear el paquete Debian
ERROR: no se puede crear o actualizar paquete ubuntu
Error: la orden package ha fallado
Cancelando
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem happened because my long description was wrong typed. You just **can't** add `\n` (manually or pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) in the long description of the app... D: