# Quickly fails to package help pages

Tags: python, application-development, quickly, helpfile

I have been working on making a program (jekyll-helper) using Quickly and a while ago I worked on adding some content to the default help pages. I tested out open the help pages in the program while running the program through the `quickly run` command, and the help pages worked fine.

However, when I made a package for the program using the `quickly package` command, installed the package, and ran the installed version of the program the help pages would not work properly. Whenever I would open the help pages via the menu option `Help > Contents`, the following error would pop up in place of the help pages:

> Document Not Found
>
> The URI ‘ghelp:jekyll-helper’ does not point to a valid page.

Unfortunately I do not know when the issue began, as I only realized that the issue existed when I ran the installed version of the program, which was a bit of time after I had finished working on the help pages.

I did some Google searching and found a few similar issues that people had, however none of them had the same exact issue as I had.

I found this question on Ask Ubuntu that seemed to be related, [Problems compiling with Quickly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161198/problems-compiling-with-quickly). That person had a similar issue, and they were able to get an error message related to the issue by running `quickly package --verbose --extras`. So I tried running that command and the package was able to build, however I got several error messages. I put up a copy of the terminal output here: http://pastie.org/10214514.

The person who wrote that issue figured out that it was caused by a new line being in the long description on the program. However, I checked my program's information in the `DistUtilsExtra.auto.setup` section of the `setup.py` file and there was no newline in the long description. Also their error message was somewhat different from the corresponding one I got. Thus the issue I am having did not likely have the same cause as the other person's issue.

I also found this somewhat related issue, [Quickly gives warnings on packageing, not recognizing setup.py~](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265848/quickly-gives-warnings-on-packageing-not-recognizing-setup-py), however that issue appears to be somewhat different from the issue I have been having. Also that issue was caused by automatic backup files created by Gedit, however I am using Atom to edit the source, which is not making such backup files.

The source code of the program is here: https://github.com/ExcaliburZero/jekyll-helper

How can this problem be fixed, and what is causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research online, I noticed that help pages for programs are generally located using URIs such as `help:ubuntu-help/index`. I compared this to the URI my program was calling `ghelp:jekyll-helper` and noticed that my program for some reason put a "g" in front of "help".

I tried running `yelp help:jekyll-helper` in the terminal and it brought up the correct help files for my program. Thus the help files were being packaged, they just weren't being called properly.

So I looked for all instances of "ghelp" in my program and found two. One in `jekyll_helper_lib/PreferencesDialog.py` and another in `jekyll_helper_lib/Window.py`. I changed the instances of "ghelp" in each to "help" and re-packaged the program with `quickly package --verbose --extras` (though I still got a few warning messages). I installed the new package and ran the program and the help pages were then working.

So it looks like the call to the help pages for some reason had a "g" character in the URI that was looked up, which was preventing it from finding the help pages, whose correct URI did not include a "g" at the beginning.